# Why doesn't VB.NET edit-and-continue work for option strict off?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've always had trouble getting edit-and-continue to work reliably.

I've reproduced the problem in this code snippet, in which edit-and-continue causes all variables to change to Nothing.

If I remove option struct off and define all the variables, then it works.  But I like option strict off because it saves substantial development time.

```
option strict off
option Explicit off


Module _Main_Module

    Sub Main()

        DO
            ' Get user command:
            user_line = CONSOLE.READLINE

            AAA=111
            
        Loop
    End Sub



End Module
```

TO CAUSE PROBLEM, DO THESE STEPS...

```
1.  Set breakpoint at line 13  
2.  run  
3.  press any key  
4.  hover over "user_line".  It contains what you typed.  
5.  Add line "BBB=222" after line 13:  
6.  Press F10 to execute next line  
7. hover over "user_line".  It is now "Nothing".
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with `Option Strict` and everything to do with `Option Explicit`. Turning `Option Strict Off` is bad enough, although there are obviously times that it is justified, but turning `Option Explicit Off` is criminal. If you have to do that to reproduce an issue then there is no issue. Why would you ever think that not declaring a variable explicitly was a good idea?

Comment: Each of these opinions fails to answer the question. Thus, I shall work around this VB edit-and-continue malfunction by turning the options both on.